# Deadman's switch: drop all tables from a database with php?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working with a client who gives me some reason not to trust him (who hasn't been in that situation).  I'm trying to create a "deadman's switch", where all tables in a database will be deleted on submission of a form (in a secret login protected directory).

What I don't know how to do is drop all tables from a database using PHP.  I know how to drop columns and rows, and am sure individual tables can be dropped (but there are a lot of tables), but all tables within a database is beyond me.

Comment: Ok, Ill repost it there, thanks!

Comment: `DROP TABLE <tablename>` :-P

Comment: `information_schema` stores the tables names.

Comment: DROP DATABASE would be easier ;-)

Comment: @RocketHazmat thanks, I was looking more towards a simple script for all tables, not having to name them individually, I have over 80 tables.

Comment: If you are going to do this at least make sure you have an up to date backup of all data before erasing the complete database.

Comment: Remind me to stay on your good side :-P

Comment: We've all been inclined to play God with people's data at some point or another. Takes a lot of confidence in your decision, to pull that switch.

Comment: @Stijn_d If the main motive is to erase, than y backup?

Comment: @RandomGuy You make me laugh.

Comment: @Nathan just accept Mr. Alien's answer then. He suggested the same.

Comment: @BenjaminPaap Agreed, it didnt show answers until i refreshed the page so all I saw were comments, Thanks everyone!

Comment: I would also recommend you delete all files (PHP, CSS, etc.) as well.

Comment: @BennyHill can I do that via php? It's literally a script that I can log into on the browser in case I get locked out of ftp, of course it's using a universal included connect to mysql script so I won't get locked out of that.

Comment: @Nathan - sure. Have a look at the unlink function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php

Comment: If you will delete all data of a client(I Don't know the context offcourse) I would always make a backup of it in case you are liable and the client would sue. Perhaps somebody will see this as an act of stealing? but as I said before, I don't know the context

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why don't you drop the entire database?

```
DROP DATABASE database_name
```

Sample Code

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['delete_database'])) {
  //Code goes here
}
?>

<form method="post">
 <input type="submit" name="delete_database" value="Delete Entire Database" />
</form>
```

Comment: What if the database you're dropping has data not related to your application? This is a potential law suit waiting to happen. If you must do it, I'd stick to only deleting tables belonging to your app, and only then with a backup/recovery in mind in case of lost data claims.

Answer (score 2):

[drop database](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/drop-database.html)

```
DROP DATABASE <DATABASE_NAME>
```

Answer (score 1):

FIrst, You can read from `information_schema`, it stores all the tables names.
Second, You can use `mysql_list_tables` (it is deprecated) to get all tables of the db. 
Third, You can drop the whole db, instead of deleting each table.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to use `DROP DATABASE`:

```
DROP DATABASE db_name;
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/drop-database.html

This would simply destroy the database. Another option would be to select all tables within the database using the `information_schema` table:

```
SELECT table_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
  WHERE table_schema = 'db_name'
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/tables-table.html

You should check the permissions of your user on the production site before you trust this idea completely though. Some hosting companies might not give you access to `information_schema` or `DROP DATABASE`.

Answer (score 1):

You can query "SHOW TABLES;" and then loop through each of those results and "DROP TABLE TABLENAME;"

But as someone already stated, if somebody else finds this and uses it. That would be a bad day. I wouldn't recommend doing this.

Comment: Thanks, honestly if someone can hack this file they could easily run the same sql query regardless if I built it or not, and I'll be deleting it or using it within the next few days, depending on if I get paid lol, not to mention I'm over the top when it comes to backing up DBs, thanks!